# Matlab subplots in loop: only shows plots in last iteration

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to create a big plot in Matlab by adding subplots in a loop.

```
% Generation of examples and targets
x = 0 : 0.05 : 3 * pi;
y = sin(x.^2);

% Deep Learning Toolbox™ software arranges concurrent vectors with a
% matrix, and sequential vectors with a cell array (where the second index is the time step).
% con2seq and seq2con allow concurrent vectors to be converted to sequential vectors, and back again.

p = con2seq(x);
t = con2seq(y); % convert the data to a useful format

% Creation of networks (based on algorlm1.m)
num_hid = 50;

% Epoch quantities to evaluate
num_epochs = [1 20 1000]

% We'll evaluate these algorithms
training_algorithms = {
    'traingd',
    'traingda',
    'traincgf',
    'traincgp',
    'trainlm',
    'trainbfg'
};

%% Initialization 

% Create arrays to store networks and training parameters
networks = cell(length(training_algorithms), 1);

durations = zeros(length(training_algorithms), 1);
slopes = cell(length(training_algorithms), 1);
intercepts = cell(length(training_algorithms), 1);
correlations = cell(length(training_algorithms), 1);

for tai = 1:length(training_algorithms)

   % Create new feedforwardnet 
   net = feedforwardnet(num_hid, training_algorithms{tai});

   % Set all networks weights and biases equal (to the first one created)
   if tai > 1
        net.IW{1,1} = networks{tai-1}.IW{1,1};
        net.LW{1,1} = networks{tai-1}.LW{1,1};
        net.b{1} = networks{tai-1}.b{1};
        net.b{2} = networks{tai-1}.b{2};
   end

   % Store network
   networks{tai} = net;

end

figure;
for tai = 1:6

   net = networks{tai}; % Load network
   net.trainParam.showWindow = false; % Don't show graph

   % Train network, and time training
   tic;
   net = train(net, p, t);
   durations(tai)=toc;

   % Simulate input on trained networks (and convert to double format)
   y_result = cell2mat(sim(net, p));

   % Evaluate result
   [slopes{tai}, intercepts{tai}, correlations{tai}] = postreg(y_result, y);

   % Add network to array
   networks{tai} = net;

   % Plot results
   subplot(2,6,tai);
   plot(x,y,'bx',x,y_result,'r'); % Plot the sine function and the output of the network
   %title('1 epoch');
   legend('target',training_algorithms{tai},'Location','north');
   subplot(2,6, tai+6);
   postregm(y_result, y); % perform a linear regression analysis and plot the result

end
```

I only get plots that were created in the last iteration though (when tai == 6). I tried adding 'hold on' in front of the loop, and turned it off again. Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: Here's the resulting figure:

[image]

EDIT2: I added code so it could be reproduced. You'll need the deep learning toolbox.

Comment: `hold on` should not be needed, since you always plot in different subplots.

Comment: Can you show how `postregm` plots? Not the whole function perhaps, but just the plotting part?

Comment: I didn't even find `postregm` in the docs just now ?!

Comment: @avermaet no me neither, I assumed it was a self written function.

Comment: https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/nnet/postreg.html

Comment: Part of the neural network toolbox. The plot above it is a regular plot though, and if I only output that part (and not the postreg), I still only get the last column.

Comment: My guess is that `postreg` includes a call to `clf` or `cla` or similar that clears the figure or axes. However just stick in a break point in the code and step through and watch as the figures get created (or not) and deleted (or not) and work out where this is happening. Either that or post an example we can run: [mre]

Comment: I just checked, and didn't see any such call. Also, if I leave out the postreg plot, and just do the regular plot (on top), I still only get the last one. I added code, it should now be reproducible.

Comment: @Inkidu616 the neural network part in your code is not that interesting, since that runs without any problem. You link to `postreg` but there is no reference page for `postregM`. I guess that if you remove the `postregm` call, the 6 top figures will be plotted correctly. Without knowing what `postregm` looks like, we cannot help you (it is not part of the Mathworks Deep learning toolbox).

Comment: Similar to @rinkert I cannot find `postregm` (with an "m" on the end). I can however see `postreg` (without the "m") which you call in your code. On line 86 of `postreg.m` I see `clf reset` for example. This could be the cause.
However I strongly suggest setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code and watch as each subplot is created, it strikes me as by far the easiest way to debug the code.
Finally on MATLAB 2018b I see `postreg` marked as obsolete, so I suggest mentioning your MATLAB version also (`ver matlab`).

Comment: Never mind, I overlooked the postreg call higher up. Thanks!